# Windows Test Driver Signing not working properly

Tags: windows, driver, signature

I'm developing a driver for Win7/8. Everything works fine and I've tried to get rid of the signature warning by following the [How to Test-Sign a Driver Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546236%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Manual from Microsoft.

I've followed all these steps but the driver appears still as "Not Digitally Signed". During the installation process the "Do you really want to trust this driver... bla bla" pops up and in the device manager the driver appears as unsigned.

The popup during installation:
[image]

The driver appears as not digitally signed in the device manager:
[image]

The cat file of the driver is signed and valid:
[image]
[image]

And the certificate is installed in the machine store (mmc.exe):
(I've also tried to put the trusted certificate in all different stores)
[image]
Does anyone have a clue what's going wrong here? I've followed exactly the suggested procedure from Microsoft.

Comment: I have the exact problem. Have you figured what's wrong here

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign the .sys file as well.